# Vector Drawable is memory efficient?

Tags: android, drawable, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory, android-vectordrawable

Sorry for putting a obvious question (?) but it is troubling me for sometime. I am using Glide for image loading and find it quite well in memory management. Now I am thinking to move to Vector drawables with the help of MrVector. Do i really need to worry about the memory management?

For further info, each of my image in JPG of size 200KB-300KB will be become just 20- 30 KB in vector drawables. If this info helps in answering the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

We had some PNG images that were only about 20kb but because we stretched them to the size of the screen, and Android converts them to bitmap in memory, they were more like 50MB!

Switching to vectors saved all of this memory.